# Is there a formula to easily find the centre of an irregular form(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, coordinates

So, I have an array that contains many of points (all points off needed figure), each with own coordinates, etc.
I want to find the point that will be at the centre of that figure, even if it's irregular. Is there's a function or formula to do that?

P.S.: My shape is not css so I want to receive the value not in pixels but in coordinates in that system

P. S. S.: If my English is not very good, please sorry

Comment: I'm sure there's some library that does this, get to googling! for example google "javascript coordinates polygon find center"

Comment: @Matthias, thanks, i have found solution using increment checking loop, but thanks for trying to help! It took me 2 weeks

Comment: Nice well done. You could consider posting your solution so others looking for your answer can benefit